# Custom Default Template for GGTS

Tags: grails, ggts

How to make a default custom template in GGTS (Groovy and Grails Tool Suite) for every time I create a new project?? i.e, every time I create a new project I get my custom made template rather the default Grails template.

Thanks in advance